# Res of $f(z)=(z+1)^4\sin(\frac{\pi}{z+1})$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Classify the singularity of $f(z)=(z+1)^4\sin(\frac{\pi}{z+1})$ at $z_0=-1$, then calculate the Res.

$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{z+1})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left (\frac{\pi}{z+1}  \right )^{2n+1}$$

$$\Rightarrow f(z)=(z+1)^4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left (\frac{\pi}{z+1}  \right )^{2n+1}=$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\frac{(\pi)^{2n+1}}{(z+1)^{2n-3}} =\pi (z+1)^3+\frac{\pi^3}{6}(z+1)^{1}+ \frac{\pi^5}{120}\frac{1}{(z+1)}+ \cdots $$

and we get that $z_0$ is an essential singularity, and $Res(f,-1)=a_{-1}=\frac{\pi^5}{120}$

**Is it correct?**

Comment: This solution ok, right ?

Comment: Yes, it is right